How to create notifications for Azure Data Sync errors or different way to schedule replication of Azure SQL data to on prem SQL Server?
We have a database in Azure SQL Server that we want to replicate continually to an On-Prem 2019 SQL Server. We are using Azure Data Sync but it fails every once in a while and we can't find out how to send alerts or notifications when errors happen with it.
We can't have something in production that doesn't notify us if it fails so does anyone know how to create those notifications or have another way to migrate the data from Azure SQL to SQL on-prem. Live replication is great but even a batch process that kicks off hourly would work for us otherwise. Trying to avoid building SSIS packages for every table if possible.
Thanks for your help! We have Googled and researched quite a bit and can't find an answer.
We have tried looking at the logging but can't seem to find the information we need or how to create the alerts in any microsoft documentation.


how to send alerts or notifications when errors happen with it.

To set the alerts for Azure Data Sync when it failed to sync the data you need to develop custom solution with the PowerShell runbook under Automation account and use an OMS workspace linked with Log Analytics workspace to create an alert.
You need to follow below steps:

You need to create a PowerShell Runbook in automation account to fetch the Data Sync log data and send it to the OMS workspace.
Using OMS workspace linked with Log Analytics workspace create an alert for the Data Sync if it is failed or got error.

Please refer to the blogpost here where you can get detailed information about the above procedure.
